# Load options in Select2 after entering partial text in select box through jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2

In Select2, I want to select an option `india`. I start typing two letters `in` in the select box. After that, I want to load the relevant data in options tags in select from a database through jQuery. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

for your example you can look for this solution: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

apart from this you can use Jquery autoComplete functionality.

apart from this you can write your own function that will send select query to your db on keydown of input text and fetch the related list to append in select box.

Comment: thanks for immediate reply @nikhil kumar.. but i want input field must be select field..(especially select2).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 2 select2 dropdowns? If yes, then on change of first select dropdown you'll to fetch related data using AJAX and load it to your target select2 dropdown, passing result object as 'data' property while initialising select2 for it.

Kindly elaborate your problem if this is not what you were looking for.

Comment: not using dependent dropdown.i want select2 field as autocomplete.after i type two letters in select2 search field then the autocomplete will get triggered with options for select.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the solution @ https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax.

**HTML Part:**

```
<select class="js-data-example-ajax">
  <option value="3620194" selected="selected">select2/select2</option>
</select>
```

**JQUERY Part:**

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2({
  ajax: {
url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories",
dataType: 'json',
delay: 250,
data: function (params) {
  return {
    q: params.term, // search term
    page: params.page
  };
},
processResults: function (data, params) {
  // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
  // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
  // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
  // scrolling can be used
  params.page = params.page || 1;

  return {
    results: data.items,
    pagination: {
      more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
    }
  };
},
cache: true
  },
  escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
  templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
});
```